# Unbound field in angular 2 formGroup

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a angular 2 RC3 dynamic form created.
Problem is that if I have fields in my html that are unbound to the formgroup (datamodel), I get the following error when running my app:

> Cannot find control 'address -> multipleAddresses'

This is a part of my html:

```
<form id="address-form" [formGroup]="form">
  <fieldset formGroupName="address">
    <input type="checkbox" name="multipleAddresses" [(ngModel)]="multipleAddresses">
```

Is there any way to ignore this unbound html input. Angular shouldn't need to check this input tag, because it actually has no formControl bound to it.

I hope anyone can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular 2 RC4 has a new form feature that fixes this issue.

After installing and being up and running with RC4 the issue was solved by adding the following to my html: `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`

Resulting in:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="multipleAddresses" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

See the RC4 changelog:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

*forms: add support for standalone ngModel dirs inside forms (6edf047), closes #9230*